# ARC with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using iOS SDK 5 to develop apps and I'm trying to use ARC. But I need to use `ASIHTTPRequest` and it's not ARC-enabled. Apple's doc said it's OK to use ARC file-based. So I compile all `ASIHTTPRequest` files with `-fno-objc-arc`. I write the following code in my class, which is using ARC:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr];
ASIHTTPRequest *req = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
req.delegate = self;
[req startAsynchronous];
```

but after executing the first line, the url is nil. What's wrong or how to use manually managed code in ARC project? Thanks.

Comment: iOS5 is still covered by an NDA, so people who know about it can't answer without breaking their agreement with Apple. Having said that, I don't think this has anything to do with ARC or iOS5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you escaped all the not ASCII characters in your URL String? If not, the NSURL instance isn't being created because it doesn't know how to handle the non-ASCII characters in your URL String. You'd need to do something like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Also, Instead of creating your own instance of NSURL, why not use Apple's helper method `URLWithString:` which will give you an 'autoreleased' NSURL instance like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
ASIHTTPRequest *req = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
req.delegate = self;
[req startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot the escaping. Thanks.

Comment: If using ARC it is more time- and space-efficient to use alloc/init than it is to use the autoreleasing methods. The difference is usually not huge but sometimes every little helps.